# Jenkins pipeline: Access individual stage result from upstream job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I've been searching and reading the Jenkins Javadoc and Jenkins CI documentation but I can't confirm if what I want is feasible or not

I have a pipeline, which is just a groovy script loaded via SCM. In this pipeline I use the `build job: 'JobName'` command. The job `JobName` looks like this:

```
node('agent-complet') {
    def phase1Success = true
    def phase2Success = true
    def phase3Success = true

    // The success flags are set to true/false in the stages...
    stage('Phase1') { ... }
    stage('Phase2') { ... }
    stage('Phase3') { ... }
}
```

What I'd like to do is know the result (success/failure flags) of each stage in the groovy script that called the job `JobName`. Is there a straight forward way of doing that?

Otherwise, I was thinking of maybe writing to a file and then read that file once the job has run its course.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Extending Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) instead of groove script.

Then you can use a class contains a dictionary of all stages:

```
package your.packagename

class Example implements Serializable {
    def mysteps = [Stage1: false, Stage2: false, Stage3: false]
    def steps

    def Example(steps) {
        this.steps = steps
    }


    def run() {
        this.steps.stage("Stage1") {
            try {
                [run some commands]
                this.mysteps["Stage1"] = true
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.mysteps["Stage1"] = false
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And then in your Jenkinsfile

```
@Library('your-library-name')
import your.packagename.Example


def pl = new Example(steps)

node {
    pl.run()
    stage("Print results") {
       sh "Results ${pl.mysteps}"
    }
}
```